# Converting openCV python function to C++

Tags: python, c++, opencv

Following fragment is stolen from openCV python samples:

```
def motion_kernel(angle, d, sz=65):
    kern = np.ones((1, d), np.float32)
    c, s = np.cos(angle), np.sin(angle)
    A = np.float32([[c, -s, 0], [s, c, 0]])
    sz2 = sz // 2
    A[:,2] = (sz2, sz2) - np.dot(A[:,:2], ((d-1)*0.5, 0))
    kern = cv2.warpAffine(kern, A, (sz, sz), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    return kern
```

It is part of a program that recover images blurred by some kind of noise.
I'm trying to convert this code to C++ but I have only a very superficial knowledge of python.
So I am in troubles in particular with line:

```
A[:,2] = (sz2, sz2) - np.dot(A[:,:2], ((d-1)*0.5, 0))
```

I understand remaining code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's write your matrix `A` as

```
A=[R | T]
```

where `R` is a `2*2` matrix and `T` is the last column of `A`. The notation `A[:,2]` in the code refers to `T`, and `A[:,:2]` refers to `R`. So, the line

```
A[:,2] = (sz2, sz2) - np.dot(A[:,:2], ((d-1)*0.5, 0))
```

is is just computing this:

```
R*v + u //v in R^2 is [(0.5(d-1)), 0]^T
        //u in R^2 is [sz2, sz2]^T
```

and then it stores it in `T` (the last column of `A`).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, because I do not see some code, but most likely:

```
A[:,:2]
```

is the matrix

```
[[c, -s]
 [s, c]]
```

Then, with

```
np.dot(A[:,:2], ((d-1)*0.5, 0))
```

we multiply that matrix by vector

```
[(d-1)*0.5, 0]
```

Actually it's tuple, not vector, but meaning is the same.

After multiplication we get some vector of two elements and we subtract that vector from

```
[sz2, sz2]
```

Finally, we replace zeros in 2x3 matrix `A` with the result of subtraction